# MySQL password is changed automatically

Tags: mysql

I'm the lone user of my computer. I haven't changed my MYSQL root user password, but it is somehow changed to empty password. Help me out !

My default sakila db is also gone. I specified engine=innodb for one of the tables.Would there be any effect

Comment: @Carsten - I understand the question sounds stupid. Is there a log to view changes done to user password ?

Comment: But have you changed anything else about your MySQL install?

Comment: I haven't. All my users are gone too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mess was because I was in middle of a crash recovery. It is good now. No ghosts,no hackers.

Answer (score 0):

This, literally, is impossible as you've described it. What has happened is something else. Either you have changed something in your installation, or some other condition has changed.

Here's how to get to the bottom of it. The MySQL database has a table, user, that lists all the users and their details. Run `'SELECT host,user,password from mysql.user;'`.

Look at the entries that have 'root' as the user. Is there more than one? Is one for localhost and the other for remote? Do they both have a password?

Now, which means of access were you trying? Were you on localhost, accessing locally? Or were you accessing from another host - which uses a different entry in the user table.

The other, more unlikely, possibility is that you have more than one installation of mysql on your host, or thirdly, that you were connecting to two different hosts. Check that out if this doesn't give you the answer.

Hopefully, this line of research will clarify for you what is going on under the covers.

Comment: @D Mac My default sakila db is also gone. I specified engine=innodb for one of the tables.Would there be any effect